# Android chromium full browser apk build issues

Tags: android, chromium

I trying to build chromium android apk with this [instruction](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/android-build-instructions)

But on [GN configuration](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/android-build-instructions#TOC-Configure-GN-recommended-) step I have following problem after arguments file editing and saving

```
ERROR at //build/config/android/internal_rules.gni:1966:13: Script returned non-zero exit code.
            exec_script("//build/android/gyp/find.py",
            ^----------
Current dir: /home/artem/chromium/src/out/Default/
Command: python -- /home/artem/chromium/src/build/android/gyp/find.py ../../third_party/android_tools/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/res
Returned 1.
stderr:

../../third_party/android_tools/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/res does not exist

See //build/config/android/rules.gni:634:3: whence it was called.
  process_resources(process_resources_target_name) {
  ^-------------------------------------------------
See //third_party/android_tools/BUILD.gn:120:1: whence it was called.
android_resources("google_play_services_default_resources") {
^------------------------------------------------------------
See //base/BUILD.gn:1074:7: which caused the file to be included.
      "//third_party/android_tools:cpu_features",
      ^-----------------------------------------
```

Then I try manually download google play services with  command [from this issue thread](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/libyuv/issues/detail?id=550):

```
sudo ./build/android/play_services/update.py download
```

And get this warning:

```
Your version of the Google Play services library is not up to date. You might run into issues building or running the app. Please run `./build/android/play_services/update.py download` to retry downloading it.
```

After that I try to build full browser apk

```
ninja -C out/Default chrome_public_apk
```

and get error:

```
ninja: Entering directory `out/Default'
ninja: fatal: chdir to 'out/Default' - No such file or directory
```

Is there the way to fix this issue and build working apk file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

1. Run this command at chromium folder:
   `git rebase-update 
   gclient sync`
2. Download google play services: 
   `sudo ./build/android/play_services/update.py download`
3. Configure GN: `gn args opt/Full`
4. Add this line to file: `target_os="android"`
5. Build apk with command: `ninja -C opt/Full chrome_public_apk`